# Invariant subspaces for action of $S_3$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V=\mathbb{F}_2v_1\oplus \mathbb{F}_2v_2$ be two dimensional space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and consider action of $S_3$ on $V$ via isomorphism $S_3\cong \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$.

Then $S_3$ acts on $V\otimes V$ which has a basis $\{v_1\otimes v_1, v_1\otimes v_2, v_2\otimes v_1, v_2\otimes v_2\}$.

$\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)=\mathrm{span}(v_1\otimes v_1, v_2\otimes v_2, v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1)$ is $S_3$ invariant subspace of $V\otimes V$.

**Q.** Is it true that this subspace has no $S_3$-invariant complement in $V\otimes V$? If yes, can one mention short steps to prove it?

Comment: You probably mean $v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_{\color{red}1}$

Comment: @Kenta: Oh, sorry; thanks for pointing it; I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complement would be $1$-dimensional, hence must be a character. $S_3$ has no nontrivial characters with values in $\mathbb F_2$, so this is equivalent to finding a $S_3$-invariant vector in $V\otimes V$.

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\&1\end{pmatrix}\in GL_2(\mathbb F_2)$ acts on $V\otimes V$ with basis $\{v_1\otimes v_1,v_1\otimes v_2,v_2\otimes v_1,v_2\otimes v_2\}$ as
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\&1&&1\\&&1&1\\&&&1\end{pmatrix},$$
so a fixed vector, if it exists, must be a linear combination of $v_1\otimes v_1$ and $v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1$. But both of these already lie in your vector space $Sym^2(V)$.